# Is this the right way to show/hide user controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I just want to ask if this is good way of showing/hiding the user controls on the main form.

I have form1 with 3 buttons (button1, button2,button3) and I have user controls (user control1, user control2,user control3 and they contain nothing).

now click button1 and user control1 shows up, and click button2 and user control2 shows up and user control1 hides.... and so on ( so ever time you click a button a user controll shows up and hides the rest.

I used the following code and it worked perfectly as i wanted but my question is:
the `UserControl.BringToFront()` function brings the user control to the front and every time you click a button it brings that usercontrol to front, so what happens to other user controls? I mean the `BringToFront()` kind of places each user control on top of another and does not remove any previous user controls. I feel like something missing, something like "Remove" function to remove the previous UserControl. And what happens if I leave my code like this (without "Remove" function? Please help. Thank you.

Here is the code and it works very well:

- user control1 name is UC1
- user control2 name is UC2
- user control2 name is UC3

  ```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          UC1 uc1 = new UC1();
          Controls.Add(uc1);
          uc1.BringToFront();

      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

          UC2 uc2 = new UC2();
          Controls.Add(uc2);
          uc2.BringToFront();

      }

      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          UC3 uc3 = new UC3();
          Controls.Add(uc3);
          uc3.BringToFront();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It doesn't bring "that" usercontrol to the front, it brings **a new** usercontrol to the front, every time. So no, this is not the right way to show/hide usercontrols. Did you look at the Show and Hide methods, or the Visible property?

Comment: Well, obviously the other UserControls are still there -- notice that you can tab to them. You're already using `Controls.Add`; did you not notice `Controls.Remove`?

Comment: Just the obvious thing, they'll no longer be in front.  If the one you pushed back in the Z-order is larger than the one you brought to the front then you can still see its edges.  The sane way to do it is to call the Dispose() method on the previous one.  *Never* call Remove(), that leaks the control and will make your program crash, eventually.  What you are doing now is leaky but at least it is not fatal, they'll still get disposed when the user closes the window.

Comment: Why not statically create the buttons and set visible=false in each click handler accordingly?

Comment: Hi Lasse V. Karlsen. yes i used show/hide but just wondering how can Remove controls

Comment: hi Joe White. yes i used Controls.Remove but I have more than 13 user control and i want to make a dynamic remove for the user control, do you know how to do it?

Comment: hi  Hans Passant. i will consider what you have said and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not *recreate* the controls each time you press the buttons, just *show/hide* the controls:

```
private UC1 uc1 = new UC1() {
  Visible = false
};

private UC2 uc2 = new UC2() {
  Visible = false
};

private UC3 uc3 = new UC3() {
  Visible = false
};

private void VisualizeUC(Control value) {
  uc1.Visible = false;
  uc2.Visible = false;
  uc3.Visible = false;

  value.Visible = true; 
} 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Controls.Add(uc1);
  Controls.Add(uc2); 
  Controls.Add(uc3);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  VisualizeUC(uc1);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  VisualizeUC(uc2);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  VisualizeUC(uc3);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry Bychenko. your code worked very well as i wanted but i did not understand this bit:    private void VisualizeUC(Control value) {
  uc1.Visible = false;
  uc2.Visible = false;
  uc3.Visible = false;

  value.Visible = true; 
}   can you please explain more? thank you

Comment: @naouf: this code *hides* all the controls of the question (`uc1`, `uc2`, `uc3`) and then shows the control provided (`value`); so if you call, say, `VisualizeUC(uc2);` all the contols except `uc2` will be hidden (`u1`, `uc3`) and `uc2` will be shown

Answer (score 0):

You were previously creating a new instance of each control every time a button was pressed which quickly adds up to lots of unnecessary controls.

Instead create and add only one instance of each control, and then hide/show as necessary:

```
// Put your controls here so they're accessible
UC1 uc1;
UC2 uc2;
UC3 uc3;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do this on form load so it only happens once

    // Instantiate your controls
    uc1 = new UC1();
    uc2 = new UC2();
    uc3 = new UC3();

    // Make them invisible
    uc1.Visible = false;
    uc2.Visible = false;
    uc3.Visible = false;

    // Add your controls
    Controls.Add(uc1);
    Controls.Add(uc2);
    Controls.Add(uc3);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You can keep using bring to front
    uc1.BringToFront();

    // OR

    // Use show/hide
    uc1.Show();
    uc2.Hide();
    uc3.Hide();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uc2.BringToFront();

    // OR show hide...
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uc3.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: hi Equalsk. your code helps alot and I changed my code accordingly,  I don't want to use ".show()" because I will have over 13 user controls and it will be confusing to show/hide them. Also I am just wondering why do not we see something like "Remove"  function to remove the previous oppend controls every time we click a button? we use BringTofront() to bring the current user control but no other function does the Remove task! .  thank you

Comment: If you don't want to repeat hide/show lots of times then follow Dmitry and make a method like the one in his example named `VisualizeUC`. Do you need to remove the controls each time? Or can you just re-use the same ones? It's not clear in your question. If you want to remove controls then don't remove them, you're best to dipose them `uc1.Dispose();`

Comment: OK clear ;) one more question please: i will use "dispose"  but do you know how to use it dynamically? as i said i have more that 13  user controls and i dont know how to do it. for example . i click button1 UserControl1 shows up and click button2 UserControl1 will dispose and UserControl2 shows up....... I mean whenever you click a button it shows up the UserControl and it disposes the previous one dynamically. can you do it dynamically? thank you